# How to dynamically assemble a typelist for passing as a variadic template parameter

Tags: c++14, c++17

I have a function that takes a variadic template parameter as its input.  What I really need to do is use some kind of magic container (typelist, tuple, etc.) to feed this function parameter.  The main problem is that this magic container needs to be dynamically assembled at runtime based on inputs to previous function calls.

Standard tuple generation obviously cannot work in this environment, so I believe some type of wrapper or helper with some typename mangling is in order, but the way to do so eludes me.  Some example pseudo-code of what I'm trying to do follows.  The user will call `AddComponent()` any number of times to add a number of components to an owning manager.  For each instance of `AddComponent()`, I need to store the passed in 'Component' type to the magic container so that I end up with a container of all the Component types that have been added.  After all this, I need to call `GetView()` using the assembled typename list as the parameter to the variadic template.  A tuple fits best here, but how to correctly assemble it?  Here's the code:

```
template<typename Component, typename ... Args>
void Blueprint::AddComponent(ComponentUsage usage, Args&& ... args)
{
// Create component object with given args

// Add 'Component' type to magic container
}

template<typename ... Component>
EntityView<Component...> EntityManager::GetView()
{
    // Create view from list of component types
}
```

Comment: You absolutely cannot have any kind of type list based on run time information. You'll need to change your approach. `EntityView` would most likely have to be a non-template class wrapping a vector of pointers to some base class, each instance of which wraps one container; details depend on exactly what `EntityView` needs to do with all those components. The search term for further research is "type erasure".

Comment: A function cannot take any kind of variadic template parameter. You can write a *function template* (**not** a function) that has a parameter pack and can be instantiated (at compile time, like any template). The result of the instantiation is a function which does not take variadic anything.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds a lot like a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and you can get *similar* behavior with syntax like this:

```
// view would be EntityView<Location, Enemy, Flying> 
auto view = makeBlueprint()
              .AddComponent<Location>(...)
              .AddComponent<Enemy>(...)
              .AddComponent<Flying>(...)
              .GetView();
```

This would use a dynamic builder where each component added would create a slightly different builder like `Builder<>` then `.AddComponent<Location>()` would return a `Builder<Location>` and then `Builder<Location, Enemy>` and so on.

However, this is still does not allow for dynamic typing; something like this would not work:

```
auto blueprint = makeBlueprint()
                   .AddComponent<Location>(...)
                   .AddComponent<Enemy>(...);

if (... some check ...)
    blueprint = blueprint.AddComponent<Flying>(...);

auto view = blueprint.GetView();
```

I doubt this solves your problem since must still be dynamically typed and is not "dynamically assembled at runtime". But I hope it offers you insight regardless.